# Creating a rest api - Post fail

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

This is my API:

```
namespace test.Api
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    public class UsersController : Controller
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext _context { get; set; }
        public UsersController([FromServices] ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Login([FromBody]LoginViewModel user)
        {
            return this.Ok("ok");
        }
    }
}
```

And my `LoginViewModel`:

```
namespace test.ViewModels
{
    public class LoginViewModel
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But it does not work:

[image]

PS: I tested the same controller with a `HttpGet` request and it works fine.

Comment: Sure thing :).  See below

Comment: use content-type: application/json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply sending the incorrect content-type, which is what the `415` status code is telling you.

If you change your content type from `raw` to `application/json`, the API will be able to process it correctly.